# How can I print a multidimensional array by the key?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array as follows:

```
$adminoptions = array(array("hello","replies",0),array("goodbye","replies",1),array("hola","flagged",0));
```

What I would like to get is 'goodbye', 'replies and '1' from `$adminoptions[1]`. I am aware that I can use the code below, however I do not wish to have to loop through each one - instead I would like to be able to do something like `$adminoptions[goodbye]`:

```
foreach($adminoptions as $array) {
   if($array[0] == 'goodbye') {
      echo ' 1) '.$adminoptions[1][0]; // goodbye
      echo ' 2) '.$adminoptions[0][1]; // replies
      echo ' 3) '.$adminoptions[0][2]; // 1
   }
}
```

Here is an example of what I would like to be able to do:

```
echo ' 1) '.$adminoptions[goodbye][0]; // goodbye
echo ' 2) '.$adminoptions[goodbye][1]; // replies
echo ' 3) '.$adminoptions[goodbye][2]; // 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not create the array and assuming that the `0` index of each sub-array is unique, then just extract them and index by the value at the `0` index:

```
$adminoptions = array_column($adminoptions, null, 0);
echo $adminoptions['goodbye'][0];
```

If you do create the array then just add a key:

```
$adminoptions = array("hello"=>array("hello","replies",0));
echo $adminoptions['hello'][0];
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I will try it now. One question though, does my array have to be in the format which you added to your answer? Or is mine fine as it is?

Comment: The first option is your format, the second option is if you are creating the array and have control over its structure.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I am creating the array so would it be more beneficial to do so in the format of the second and would it make it easier to do what I asked in my question?

Comment: Yes, then you wouldn't need my first option.

Comment: Brilliant, didn't know I could do it like that with multidimensional arrays. Thanks again!

Comment: @TheCodesee You should also make the values associative arrays, like `$adminoptions = array("hello" => array("key" => "hello", "value" => "replies", "number" => 0));`. Indexed arrays should be used for uniform data, associative arrays for heterogeneous data.